# Question about naming conventions for Cocoa/Objective-C for iPhone (with respect to release and autorelease)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4

Can you describe the naming convention difference between a method that returns an object it has allocated for the caller (and that the caller should release), and a method that returns an autorelease object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB):

1. methods that start with -allocXXX or -newXXX, or contains the word "copy" will/should return an allocated object
2. any method that doesn't follow rule #1 will/should return an autoreleased object

Comment: What about create? Does that prefix retain or autorelease?

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, a create prefix on an objective-c method means you are NOT responsible for releasing the result, whereas  create in a CF... function means you ARE responsible for releasing the result. Weird... http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: apple doc link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Answer (score 7):

Methods that return a retained object (which the caller should release) should include the word `copy`, `new`, `mutableCopy`, or `alloc` (as in an `alloc`/`init` pair). Everything else should return an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 7):

Did you have a look at[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If the method has alloc, new, copy or create in the name, it will return a new, retained object, by convention.