# MKAnnotationView: Memory leak

Tags: ios, ios4, memory-leaks, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using the following code to make a pin for annotation:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)           annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    return annView;
}
```

Everything works perfectly, however Analyze in XCode shows memory leak in this code. In fact, I see it too cos I allocated object and then did not released it.
How can I avoid memory leak here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't wrote, but I think analyzer tells you what it leaks here:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                                 initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                    reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
```

Thats because you need autorelease item:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                     reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"] autorelease];
```

**UPDATE**

Also you don't reuse created annotations, try do this:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
if(annView == nil) 
    annView = annView=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                         initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                            reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"] autorelease];
```

Comment: Check my update, this will speedup your code and reduce memory usage, because you instantly create new objects all the time instead of reuse already created.

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, I see it too cos I allocated object and then did not released it.

You are right about the reason of the leak. If you need to return an alloced object from a method then the idea is to autorelease that.

```
- (MyClass *)getObject {
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    return [obj autorelease];
}
```

Then you will retain the returned object in caller if needed.

Or name the method in such a way that it is clear that the returned object need to be released in caller. And then release in the caller.

Comment: What do you mean by _Or name the method in such a way that it is clear that the returned object need to be released in caller. And then release in the caller._?

And is there any difference between
`- (MyClass *)getObject {
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    return [obj autorelease];
}
`
and

`- (MyClass *)getObject {
    MyClass *obj = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    return obj;
}`?

Comment: Both of your examples are same. There is no practical difference here. By naming I mean to follow the convention that is widely used in iOS so that the caller knows when it owns the returned object (and thus need to release the returned object) and when it is getting an autoreleased object. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979945/question-about-naming-conventions-for-cocoa-objective-c-for-iphone-with-respect

Comment: By convention, the name mapView:viewForAnnotation: means it returns an autoreleased object and the caller needs to retain it if needed. And the name like newMapView:viewForAnnotation: means it retuns an alloced object and thus the caller need to release that. You are extremely encouraged to follow the naming conventions.